# Get hours an minutesfrom NSDate

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate

I saved a date in a sqlite database. Know I try to get the hours and the minutes. But the hours are shifted by 2.

```
print(calendar.timeZone)
while result.next() {
                var hour = 0
                var minute = 0
                let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
                if #available(iOS 8.0, *) {
                    calendar.getHour(&hour, minute: &minute, second: nil, nanosecond: nil, fromDate: result.dateForColumn("time"))
                    print(result.dateForColumn("time"))
                    print("the hour is \(hour) and minute is \(minute)")
                }

            }
```

I get the following output:

```
Europe/Berlin (GMT+2) offset 7200 (Daylight)
2016-08-17 18:44:57 +0000
the hour is 20 and minute is 44
2016-08-18 18:44:57 +0000
the hour is 20 and minute is 44
2016-08-19 15:44:57 +0000
the hour is 17 and minute is 44
2016-08-18 16:44:57 +0000
the hour is 18 and minute is 44
2016-08-17 18:44:57 +0000
the hour is 20 and minute is 44
2016-08-18 18:44:57 +0000
the hour is 20 and minute is 44
2016-08-19 15:44:57 +0000
the hour is 17 and minute is 44
2016-08-18 16:44:57 +0000
the hour is 18 and minute is 44
```

The timezone is correct. I tryed two other solutions. But it is always the same problem.

Comment: There is no problem, the output is correct. `print(someDate)` prints in UTC, and the date components are in your local timezone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `result.dateForColumn("time")` is in `UTC` since you have `+0000` whereas the second output is in another timezone (`Europe/Berlin (GMT+2)`), so the date is the same.